# VBA - Boolean value is converted to a string

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add the following formula dynamical to a cell in Excel.

```
=HVIS(ER.FEJL(LOPSLAG(B" & ActiveCell.row & ",VareKategorier,2,FALSK)),"""",LOPSLAG(B" & ActiveCell.row & ",VareKategorier,2,FALSK))
```

becomes

```
=HVIS(ER.FEJL(LOPSLAG(B3;VareKategorier;2;'FALSK'));"";LOPSLAG(B3;VareKategorier;2;'FALSK'))
```

but as you can see the boolean value FALSK (danish word for FALSE) is converted to a string 'FALSK'.

[image]

Why is it doing this and how can I fix my formula to get it working?

Complete code

```
        For Each raekke In .Range("A3", "E" & celle).Rows
            raekke.Select
            Dim formulaKat As String
            Dim formulaUKat As String
            If ekstra = True Then
                formulaKat = "=HVIS(ER.FEJL(LOPSLAG(B" & _
                ActiveCell.row & _
                ",VareKategorierIgloMolok,2,FALSK)),"""",HVIS(LOPSLAG(B" & _
                ActiveCell.row & _
                ",VareKategorierGenbrug,2,FALSK)=0,"""",LOPSLAG(B" & _
                ActiveCell.row & _
                ",VareKategorierIgloMolok,2,FALSK)))"
                Range("D" & ActiveCell.row).Formula = formulaKat
                formulaUKat = "=HVIS(ER.FEJL(LOPSLAG(B" & _
                ActiveCell.row & _
                ",VareKategorierIgloMolok,3,FALSK)),"""",HVIS(LOPSLAG(B" & _
                ActiveCell.row & _
                ",VareKategorierIgloMolok,3,FALSK)=0,"""",LOPSLAG(B" & _
                ActiveCell.row & _
                ",VareKategorierIgloMolok,3,FALSK)))"
                Range("E" & ActiveCell.row).Formula = formulaUKat
            Else
                formulaKat = "=HVIS(ER.FEJL(LOPSLAG(B" & _
                ActiveCell.row & _
                ",VareKategorierGenbrug,2,FALSK)),"""",HVIS(LOPSLAG(B" & _
                ActiveCell.row & _
                ",VareKategorierGenbrug,2,FALSK)=0,"""",LOPSLAG(B" & _
                ActiveCell.row & _
                ",VareKategorierGenbrug,2,FALSK)))"
                Range("D" & ActiveCell.row).Formula = formulaKat
                formulaUKat = "=HVIS(ER.FEJL(LOPSLAG(B" & _
                ActiveCell.row & _
                ",VareKategorierGenbrug,3,FALSK)),"""",HVIS(LOPSLAG(B" & _
                ActiveCell.row & _
                ",VareKategorierGenbrug,3,FALSK)=0,"""",LOPSLAG(B" & _
                ActiveCell.row & _
                ",VareKategorierGenbrug,3,FALSK)))"
                Range("E" & ActiveCell.row).Formula = formulaUKat
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
sformula = "=HVIS(ER.FEJL(LOPSLAG(B" & _
            ActiveCell.Row & _
            ",VareKategorier,2,FALSK)),"""",LOPSLAG(B" & _
            ActiveCell.Row & _
            ",VareKategorier,2,FALSK))"

Range("A1").Formula = sformula
```

Comment: @siddhart-rout Using your code I get the same result as before.
`code`=HVIS(ER.FEJL(LOPSLAG(B3;VareKategorier;2;'FALSK'));"";LOPSLAG(B3;VareKategorier;2;'FALSK'))

Comment: Can you click on the cell and then take a screenshot of the formula bar?. upload the screenshot on any free file sharing site and then share the link here.

Comment: Also try `Range("A1").FormulaLocal = sformula`

Comment: Did you try my last suggestion?

Comment: FormulaLocal didn't work, got a Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Can you update your question with the complete code on how are you assigning the formula to the cell>